# q.all seems to behave differently, why?

Tags: javascript, promise, q

Here is my code that I would expect would start from the top and execution would continue on down. The first two clauses get a record from the database and then update the 'self' object. However, when the execution hits the Q.all, the method returns Promises rather than actually resolving the promises and putting the value into locs(and eventually 'self'). Eventually, the promises will get resolved, but *after* the 'return self' in the last then clause. I need self.locations to be set before 'return self' is run.

```
return dao.getRecords(APP_COLLECTION, filters).then(function(data) {
    return self.loadClientAppImpl(data);
}).then(function() {
    locArray = self.app.field_194_raw;
    return dao.getChildren("object_23", self.appId, "field_210", "field_164").then(function(knackRecord) {
        self.priorCarriers = knackRecord.records;
    });
}).then(function() {
    var locPromiseArray = getPromisesArray(locArray);
    return Q.all(locPromiseArray).then(function(locs){
        self.locations = locs;
    });
}).then(function() {
    return self;
}).done();
```

I thought that the multiple promises were supposed to act like the single call promises as well?

ie. dao.getRecords is fine, but why does the Q.all([dao.getRecords1, dao.getRecord2 etc]) not work as I might expect (ie. doesn't resolve before 'return self;')?

The following code works fine, I replaced Q.all with a single promise and everything works as expected (ie. return self called last in chain). The question remains: why does Q.all not work the same? I'm assuming this is just the way its supposed to work and I don't understand something about the implementation.

```
return dao.getRecords(APP_COLLECTION, filters).then(function(data) {
    self.loadClientAppImpl(data);
}).then(function() {
    locArray = self.app.field_194_raw;
    return dao.getChildren("object_23", self.appId, "field_210", "field_164").then(function(knackRecord) {
        self.priorCarriers = knackRecord.records;
    });
}).then(function() {
    var locPromiseArray = getPromiseArray(locArray);
    return locPromiseArray[0].then(function(locs){
        self.locations = locs;
    });
}).then(function() {
    return self;
}).done();
```

Here is the getPromisesArray method

```
function getPromiseArray (locArray) {
    var locationCollection = "object_22";
    //create a promise for all of the records
    var locationPromiseArray = [];
    if(locArray[0]){
        var locId0 = locArray[0].id;
        //dao.getRecord returns a promise
        locationPromiseArray.push(dao.getRecord(locationCollection, locId0));
    }       

    if(locArray[1]){
        var locId1 = locArray[1].id;
        locationPromiseArray.push(dao.getRecord(locationCollection, locId1));
    }

    if(locArray[2]){
        var locId2 = locArray[2].id;
        locationPromiseArray.push(dao.getRecord(locationCollection, locId2));
    }            

    if(locArray[3]){
        var locId3 = locArray[3].id;
        locationPromiseArray.push(dao.getRecord(locationCollection, locId3));
    }
    return locationPromiseArray;
};
```

Thanks for any help!

Mark

PS. I noticed that the code below behaves differently, and I would have expected it to work the same way. Starting to wonder if I found a bug. In the first case, 'results' is filled with the values (as it should be). In the second case, 'results' is a promise. Shouldn't they be the same one way or another?

```
return dao.getRecords(APP_COLLECTION, filters).then(function(data) {
    self.loadClientAppImpl(data);
}).then(function() {
    return dao.getChildren("object_23", self.appId, "field_210", "field_164");
}).then(function(knackRecord) {
    self.priorCarriers = knackRecord.records;
    locPromiseArray = getPromiseArray(self.app.field_194_raw);
    return Q.all(locPromiseArray).then(function(results){
            self.locations = results;
            return self;  
    });
});

return dao.getRecords(APP_COLLECTION, filters).then(function(data) {
    self.loadClientAppImpl(data);
}).then(function() {
    return dao.getChildren("object_23", self.appId, "field_210", "field_164");
}).then(function(knackRecord) {
    self.priorCarriers = knackRecord.records;
    locPromiseArray = getPromiseArray(self.app.field_194_raw);
    return Q.all(locPromiseArray);
}).then(function(results){
        self.locations = results;
        return self;  
});
```

Comment: Sorry, but I don't completely understand the problem. In the last `then` you create a promise using `Q.all` and then you - in the inner `then` call - resolve this promise with a value `self`. The first `return` then contains a promise which will be eventually resolved with the `self` value.

Comment: Yes, exactly right. The question I have is the execution order of it all. I have a method that is calling this, and if I remove the last 'then' clause (the one with the Q.all in it) then the caller would get 'self' after the previous two then clauses have completed (resolved). But with Q.all, the caller gets unresolved promises. I want the caller to get the resolved answers instead. I'll update the code to make it a bit clearer

Comment: Show us your `getPromiseArray` method. Doesn't it return an array of promises?

Comment: The `return self;` part should happen after all promises listed in the `Q.all` are fulfilled. The caller should get a promise - created by the `done` call - which should be eventually fulfilled with `self`. This code should work exactly like this. If it's returning something else then you have probably a different code.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Radek. But this is the code and if I set breakpoints, I can see that 'return self;' occurs immediately following the 'return Q.all(...)' call. And I can see the other calls work fine (ie. 'return self.loadClientAppImpl(data);' and 'self.priorCarriers = knackRecord.records;')

Comment: It should run as following:
1. getRecords
2. data -> loadClientAppImpl
3. appImpl -> getChildren
4. knackRecord -> self.priorCarriers
5. undefined -> Q.all
6. locs -> self.locations
7. undefined -> return self
8. self -> done

If it really does something else, could you provide a live example?

Comment: If its any help, when I set the breakpoints, the 'self.locations = locs' line happens during some 'flush' call inside of the q library, which is different than in the other clauses!

Comment: Radek - yes, that exactly the way the calls go, until step 6, and then return self is called, and then then does self.locations, sigh.

Comment: That's weird. Maybe try returning just the `Q.all` and the `then` call move to the chain before `return self;`. If this won't work, I'm out of ideas. :D

Comment: This would be much simpler if you use Bluebird and `.bind` by the way.

Comment: @MarkWaschkowski, "running the promises" is a conceptually wrong. Maybe you need to go back to basics.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 you could well be right, I'm still getting to know Q and promises. Any insight into the updated example and the difference?

Comment: Mark, it's a tricky topic area. I'm engrossed in the Tour de France right now but will take another look later.

Comment: @MarkWaschkowski As I said, try to move the inner `then` call to the main chain.

Comment: @Radek - tried, no change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the answer is fairly simple, its all about the return type and how promises are set up to work, which for Q is called propagation and discussed here:

https://github.com/kriskowal/q

To Quote:

```
var outputPromise = getInputPromise()
  .then(function (input) {
    }, function (reason) {
  });
```

> If you return a value in a handler, outputPromise will get fulfilled.
>
> If you throw an exception in a handler, outputPromise will get
>   rejected.
>
> If you return a promise in a handler, outputPromise will “become” that
>   promise. Being able to become a new promise is useful for managing
>   delays, combining results, or recovering from errors.

The above is a case where either a value is returned or a Promise. The key is what is the caller of this expecting? In my case, its expecting a value. That works when using promises like so (first case):

```
return dao.getRecords(APP_COLLECTION, filters).then(function(data) {
    self.loadClientAppImpl(data);
}).then(function() {
    locArray = self.app.field_194_raw;
    return dao.getChildren("object_23", self.appId, "field_210", "field_164").then(function(knackRecord) {
        self.priorCarriers = knackRecord.records;
    });
}).then(function() {
    var locPromiseArray = getPromiseArray(locArray);
    return locPromiseArray[0].then(function(locs){
        self.locations = [locs];
    });
}).then(function() {
    return self;
}).done();
```

'self' is eventually returned, and the caller is happy because that's what it is expecting, a value. However, with the following code (from the original question), a value is not returned, a promise is returned instead (second case):

```
return dao.getRecords(APP_COLLECTION, filters).then(function(data) {
    return self.loadClientAppImpl(data);
}).then(function() {
    locArray = self.app.field_194_raw;
    return dao.getChildren("object_23", self.appId, "field_210", "field_164").then(function(knackRecord) {
        self.priorCarriers = knackRecord.records;
    });
}).then(function() {
    var locPromiseArray = getPromisesArray(locArray);
    return Q.all(locPromiseArray).then(function(locs){
        self.locations = locs;
    });
}).then(function() {
    return self;
}).done();
```

ie. when using Q.all, you get a promise that needs to be resolved, whereas in the first case self (a value) is returned.

I've considerably cleaned up and optimized the code now, but I wanted to close the loop on this for others in case it might help them.

btw - from the calling code, there is an easy way around this situation, Q provide a 'when' method that you can use in case you aren't sure if you are getting back a Promise or a value:

```
return Q.when(valueOrPromise, function (value) {
}, function (error) {
});
```

I ended up putting this in place to test the two scenarios and could see that the 'valueOrPromise' variable was either populated with a value (first case) or a Promise (second case).

Thanks to everyone that contributed to figuring this out - cheers!

Comment: You're saying that `dao.getRecord` did not always return a promise, and that `Q.all()` did not automatically cast non-promise values?

Comment: No, what I'm saying is that Q.all returns with something deferred rather than being resolved, whereas ALL of the rest of the promises were resolved.

Comment: Of course `Q.all` does return a promise whose resolution is *deferred* until all the input promises are fulfilled? But it must not matter to your script whether a promise is already resolved or still pending.

Comment: As stated in the original post: " Eventually, the promises will get resolved, but after the 'return self' in the last then clause. I need self.locations to be set before 'return self' is run."

Comment: @Bergi As stated in the original post: " Eventually, the promises will get resolved, but after the 'return self' in the last then clause. I need self.locations to be set before 'return self' is run." This does not happen when using Q.all, and the caller of the code must handle it one way or another, that is the difference. ie. what the caller of the code (not shown) gets back is different depending on if Q.all is used, or a series of single promises. That is what makes Q.when nice - it handles both of those cases transparently.

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to see why substituting a single promise for `Q.all(...)` gives the desired result. It's possible that your analysis of exactly what's going on is not correct.

However, here are some ideas.

A mid-chain `.then()` isn't necessary unless it filters by returning a new promise or a different value. A mid-chain `.then()` whose callback does nothing more than make an assignemnt is a candidate for the chop. You have two such assignments.

- self.priorCarriers = knackRecord.records;
- self.locations = locs;

It's easy to make mistakes in things like this, but I think your main block of code will rearrange as follows :

```
return dao.getRecords(APP_COLLECTION, filters).then(function(data) {
    return self.loadClientAppImpl(data);
}).then(function() {
    return dao.getChildren("object_23", self.appId, "field_210", "field_164");
}).then(function(knackRecord) {
    self.priorCarriers = knackRecord.records;
    return Q.all(getPromisesArray(self.app.field_194_raw));
}).then(function(locs) {
    self.locations = locs;
    return self;
}).done();
```

Note that the assignments are now in functions that also return something, and importantly `self.locations = locs` is in the same function that returns `self`. This may or may not fix your issue though it is *promising* [sic].

For the record, `getPromiseArray()` should also simplify as follows :

```
function getPromiseArray (locArray) {
    return locArray.map(function(loc) {
        return dao.getRecord("object_22", loc.id);
    });
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I'm using your getPromiseArray now, its nice. I've updated the original question, but still not sure of what is going on. I guess I'll have to do a fiddle, unless you have any other ideas?

Comment: In can only think that one or more of your `dao.getRecord()` calls fails. Try adding a `catch(...)` at the end of the `.then` chain to log the potential error.